# Recording script not working for Xiaomia for android App

Tags: android

We are try to records the call form our app its working fine for all other device except Xiaomi Note 3 and other MI devices . is any ways or setting need to change for run properly this below recording code in Xiaomi type device

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                recorder.setOutputFile(fname);
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.start();
                    recording=true;
                    ts=getCurrentTS();

                    editor.putString("mdialerRecording", "true");editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recorder_Initialized1111 catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                   File recfile = new File(fname);if(recfile.exists())recfile.delete();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: i am facing the same issue